# Can I resubmit the article?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, errors-erratum

I submitted my revised paper (second-time major revision) just few days back through Scholar One. Now I found some errors in my submitted paper. As the paper is already submitted, what shall I do? Can I write a mail to the editor-in-chief?

Comment: Depends upon the specific journal's policy and system. Have you contacted them? I doubt anyone here can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can’t change the submission once it’s gone through.

If the errors are truly minor (typos and grammar errors), then it’s not worth it to go through the trouble of alerting the editor. Just correct the problem before the next stage.

If it’s a material error (including the wrong version of a figure, for example), then you should alert the editor and ask for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can email the editor or the handling editor about the error you made in the submission and it's important to include your Manuscript # or code so they can easily track it. I experienced before I mistakenly uploaded a different cover letter for a different manus. I emailed and explained the case what they did was reopened the system so I can modify my submission, however, the "Date Submitted" has changed.